# Is the Vietoris topology on compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ locally convex?

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-vector-spaces, locally-convex-spaces, set-valued-analysis

The title question says it all really.

If the question is negative for compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$, is it affirmative for compact and convex subsets of $\mathbb R^n$? How about for all nonempty subsets of $\mathbb R^n$?

If the answer is affirmative, does the result also hold for all locally convex topological vector spaces?

Comment: Let me know if i misunderstood the question. Take a V shape $K$ on the plane, and engulf it with a thin open set $U$.  The set $V=\{L\subset U\}$ is open in the Vietoris topology. Assume that $K\in W\subset V$ is convex. But then $(K+K)/2\in W$. However, $(K+K)/2$ contains the middle between the ends of the V, and so $(K+K)/2$ is not even included in $U$.

Comment: I've encountered local convexity only as a property of topological vector spaces. Since the space of compact subsets of $\mathbb R^n$ isn't naturally a vector space, it's not clear to me what the question means. The comment by @bof uses a reasonable-looking interpretation of "locally convex" for this situation, but maybe some other interpretation was intended.

Comment: The hyperspace of compact convex sets indeed has a convexity structure as we can take Minkowski convex combinations $tA+(1-t)B=\{ta+(1-t)b:a\in A, b\in B\}$ of compact convex sets. So, for the hyperspace of compact convex sets there is sense to speak about the local convexity. It suffices to check that the balls in Hausdorff metric around compact convex sets are convex in the sense of the Minkowski operation (which should be true).

Comment: I had in mind using Minkowski sums, as Taras Banakh suggested. I don't know why I didn't realize it when I was writing the question, but I guess the subsets should be compact _and_ convex.